# Generalizing Key input using the pygame module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to make a class "Player" that has a list containing the inputs I want as strings, like `['w','a','s','d']` ,
and using the pygame module to get all the pressed keys through `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, find a way to generalize the conditions:

`keys_pressed[pygame.K_w]`|`keys_pressed[pygame.K_a]`|`keys_pressed[pygame.K_s]`|`keys_pressed[pygame.K_d]`
,using the list of keys from the Player class.

pseudo-code:

`player.list = ['w','a','s','d']`

`keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()`

`if keys_pressed[pygame.K_<player.list[0]>]:move up`

`if keys_pressed[pygame.K_<player.list[1]>]:move left`

`if keys_pressed[pygame.K_<player.list[2]>]:move down`

`if keys_pressed[pygame.K_<player.list[3]>]:move right`

Is there a way I can implement this? If so, what's the right way to concatenate the "K_" + list[i] so that pygame accepts it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that. Why do not use a list `[pygame.K_w, pygame.K_a, pygame.K_s, pygame.K_d]`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 mainly because of the "pygame.K_" repetition. If that's the only way to implement, okay, but I wanted to see if a less repetitive way was possible :)

Comment: There is no repetition. `K_a` is different to `K_w`.

Comment: *"A long descriptive name is better than a short enigmatic name. A long descriptive name is better than a long descriptive comment."*  
Robert C. Martin, Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship

Comment: I got it working using the way you suggested, so thanks!